# Insert JSON from URL string

Tags: c#, json, url

I have created a REST web service that should get a JSON string and convert it to an object in C#.  I have created my classes  and used the deserialization:

```
RootObject test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("id");
```

So far so good, I need to call my function :

```
public string JSONData(string id)
```

Is there a way to insert my JSON in the URL so I can trigger my function, or am I missing something fundamental?

```
http://localhost/RestSrv/Json/....
```

What should I put in the `...` that will give value to my id string and call my JSONData function that will deserialize the JSON after? Should I use an online JSON convert to URL tool?

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request, it explains how to include params in both a GET and POST request

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this

1. Send JSON via HTTP POST with **Content-Type: application/json** header
2. Send HTTP Query String with the required data. For example

   ?object[type]=person&children_names[]=Mia&children_names[]=Anna

Would convert to JSON (https://www.convertonline.io/convert/query-string-to-json)

```
{"object":{"type":"person"},"children_names":["Mia","Anna"]}
```

Option 1 is better since URL string can be long and have a length limitation.